# Why is the card not showing in the canvas? (Python)

Tags: python, image

First of all, I am sorry for my poor English. I am writing a simple Blackjack game with Python.
However, I couldn't make the 4 cards appear on the canvas. They just kind of get overlapped on each other, which is not what I want it to be.
The following code is a definition of draw_card(dealer, player). Each parameter, dealer and player are lists of card objects, which I have defined in the Card class above(not shown in the code). I know that this is limited information, but can I get some advice or help, please?

[What I want the canvas to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mj4P0.png) and
[What I got instead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21z77.png)

def draw_card(dealer,player):

```
depth = 100
(x0,y0) = (100,100)
(x1,y1) = (100,300)

bj_board.clear()

for element in dealer:
    bj_board.add(element.image())
for element in player:
    bj_board.add(element.image())



for i in range(len(dealer)):
    
    dealer[i].image().moveTo(100+20*i, 100)
    dealer[i].image().setDepth=100-20*i
    text1=Text("The dealer's Total: " + str(hand_value(dealer)))
    text1.moveTo(550, 100)
    
    
for j in range(len(player)):
    
    player[j].image().moveTo(100+20*i, 300)
    player[j].image().setDepth=100-20*i
    text2=Text("Your Total: " + str(hand_value(player)))
    text2.moveTo(550, 300)
```